# Django update all objects on html rows via save button

Tags: django

As per the below image I want to create a form where I can update the edited values. So far I can get the data from the request._post and loop thru the values and update them. Is there a better / simpler way of doing this ?

[image]

```
######################## MODEL #####################
class sampleModel(models.Model):
    primaryKey = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

######################## VIEW #####################
def sampleModel_list_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass #DO SOMTHING    
    objs = sampleModel.objects.all()
    context={'objs':objs,'title':'List of all objects'}
    return render(request,'sampleModel_list.html',context)

######################## HTML #####################
<form method='POST' action='.' enctype='multipart/form-data'> {% csrf_token %}
    {% for obj in objs %}
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-body'>
                    <input type='text' name='primaryKey' placeholder='' value='{{obj.primaryKey}}' />
                    <input type='text' name='text' placeholder='' value='{{obj.text}}' />   
            </div>  
        </div>
    {% endfor%}
    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-success" value='Save'/>
```

Comment: You've cut out the relevant part of your view. What is DO SOMETHING?

Comment: Thats the part I need help with. For now I can get the data from the request._post , loop through it and save

Comment: I'm not clear what you actually want. Please show what the code is now.